# Exterior Algebra of module over group ring

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R = \mathbb{Z}[G]$ be a group ring where $G = \{1, \sigma \}$, and let $M = \mathbb{Z}e_{1} + \mathbb{Z}e_{2}$ be a free $\mathbb{Z}$ module of rank $2$, and basis $e_{1}, e_{2}$. Define $\sigma (e_{1}) = e_{1} + 2e_{2}$ and $\sigma(e_{2}) = -e_{2}$. Show that $\Lambda^{2}(M)$ is a group of order $2$ (as an $R$-module), with generator $e_{1} \wedge e_{2}$. 
I am able to show that under the given operations $M$ is an $R$-module. By the property of the exterior algebra, $\Lambda^{2}(M)$ has rank $\binom{2}{2} = 1$, and has a basis $e_{1} \wedge e_{2}$. 
I am confused as to what they mean by "is a group of order 2 generated by $e_{1} \wedge e_{2}$"? 
I know that $(e_{1} \wedge e_{2})(e_{1} \wedge e_{2}) = 0$. Can someone clear up for me what I have to show to prove that $\Lambda^{2}(M)$ is a group of order $2$